# laravel 4 workbench routing to the package

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, package, laravel-routing

I have been working with laravel 4 for some time now and i needed to create an admin area so i decided to use a package to keep things all organized and separated from the rest of the application.

So i created a package with composer as 'vendor/admin'.

then i added those lines as documemented on laravel site

AdminServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->package('vendor/admin', 'admin');
        include __DIR__.'/../../routes.php';
 }


public function register()
    {
        //
        $this->package('vendor/admin');

    }
```

I also created a routes.php file in vedor/admin/ directory to route all admin area in this file.

following  i run the '`php artisan dump-autoload`' and i finalized with this commend on artisan '`php artisan config:publish vendor/admin`'

now i wanna be able use this package for mysite.com/admin route and i want the routes.php file in the package to render the routing for that URI, to do that:

1. Do i need to modify my app/routes.php?
2. How can i make vendor/admin/src/routes.php file to do the routing for all mysite.com/admin routes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't need to edit `app/routes.php`. As long as it doesn't contain any `admin` routes that could collide with the ones in your package you can leave it that way.

The routes file in a package can be used like the "normal" `app/routes.php`. An easy way to deal with `admin` routes is to have a prefix group:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function(){
    // all your admin routes. for example:
    Route::get('dashboard', '...');
    // will match GET /admin/dashboard
});
```

Besides that, make sure you're package gets loaded correctly! One part being **registering the service provider**. Assuming the namespace of your package is `Admin` you need to add `Admin\AdminServiceProvider` to the providers array in `app/config/app.php`. [More information](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/packages#creating-a-package)

Comment: this is what a have Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function(){
    // all your admin routes. for example:
    Route::get('/', function(){
        return 'you are at admin area';
    });
    // will match GET /admin/dashboard
}); but it throws "controller method not found".
i guess it does not use my routes.php in the package

Comment: Do you have another admin route inside `app/routes.php`?

Comment: Thanks. I believe the `/{path}` route is catching the request because it matches pretty much everything. (including `admin`). I'll update my answer in a minute

Comment: thanks. But i actually tested it by commenting out that line and still the same error occurs.

Comment: Just in case, do not forget to add the admin service provider to `/config/app.php` file

Comment: For testing, add `dd('routes.php')` at the beginning of your routes file to see if it get's loaded (it should output "routes.php" in the browser)

Comment: @manix, can you tell me how do i add it to my app.php ? Because i dont see any changes in that file for the package

Comment: @lukasgeiter i did what you said and it is not being loaded.

Comment: @JustinM.Ucar ok. Assuming the namespace of your package is `Admin` you need to add `Admin\AdminServiceProvider` to the `providers` array in `app/config/app.php`

Comment: exactly, follow @lukasgeiter's advice

Comment: Woo Hoo, I just did that and it fired up just perfect. thanks a lot. Can you add that line to the answer and i will mark it as the answer please?